# Query react native always with record number of one

Tags: reactjs, fetch, unique, native, record

I have created an API that allows me to do a query via react native.
The extracted data is correct, but unfortunately I always get a record number length of one. Even if the data is empty, the length of the received array is always 1.
This is the code and you can see where I put the alert to see the length of the array

```js
var SearchAPIURL = 'http://www.mysite/api/search.php';

var header = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

var Data = {
    FindRollNo: myFindRollNo,
};

fetch(SearchAPIURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: header,
    body: JSON.stringify(Data),
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
    alert(response.length);
    
    setRollNo(response[0].RollNo);
    setStudentName(response[0].StudentName);
    setCourse(response[0].Course);
})
```

Please... Help me...

Comment: The problem most likely is on the server code. Please add it too.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
In fact, the API used was written in such a way that it always sends an array with a length of at least one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).